# How to redirect user to store other than playstore (huawei-store, oppo-store, 9apps-store, etc)?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

I upload an apk in oppostore,vivostore,xiaomistore,samsungstore,9apps,huaweistore, also playstore. When I have update, I want redirect user to store that they used. For example : if they install from huaweistore, I want redirect user to huaweistore. I find deeplink to playstore and samsung store, but for the other stores I haven't find it until now. Do you know deeplink to those store?

I can open the store but not using deeplink. So, it's open user's browser

Here what I used now :
To update app in samsung store I used this

```java
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("samsungapps://ProductDetail/<my-package-name>")));
```

To open playstore, I used this

```java
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<my-package-name>")));
```

For the other store, because I don't know the deeplink, I use this (open browser)

```java
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https:...<link to the app>")));
```

I want redirect user to store that they used. If you know the deeplink one or all of the deeplink to those store (oppostore,vivostore,xiaomistore,9apps,huaweistore) really appriciate if you put a comment & let me know. It will really help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the deeplink of Huawei App Gallery: `appmarket://details?id=(your package name)`